# IsUsersInGroup(int groupId, int firstuserUserId, int secondUserId)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have `UserTable`:

```
UserName
UserId (primarykey)
```

I have `GroupTable`:

```
GroupName
Groupd (primarykey)
```

I am  relating each user with  group with 3rd table `UserGroup`:

```
UserId
GroupId
```

How can I implement the function

```
bool IsUsersInGroup(int groupId, int firstuserUserId, int secondUserId)
```

that returns true if both firstuserUser and secondUser is associated with  group with groupId?
using  entity-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool IsUserInGroup(int groupId, int userId)
{
 using (var db = new Model1Container())
 {
  return ((from ug in db.UserGroup
     join user in db.UserTable on new { a = ug.UserId, b = userId } equals new { a = user.UserId, b = user.UserId }
     join gr in db.GroupTable on new { a = ug.GroupId, b = groupId } equals new { a = gr.GroupId, b = gr.GroupId }
     select ug)
  .FirstOrDefault()) != null;
 }
}

bool IsUsersInGroup(int groupId, int user1Id, int user2Id)
{
 return IsUserInGroup(groupId, user1Id) && IsUserInGroup(groupId, user2Id);
}
```

or

```
bool IsUserInGroup(int groupId, int user1Id, int user2Id)
{
 using (var db = new Model1Container())
 {
  return ((
   from ug1 in db.UserGroup
   from ug2 in db.UserGroup
   join user in db.UserTable on new { a = ug1.UserId, b = user1Id } equals new { a = user.UserId, b = user.UserId }
   join gr in db.GroupTable on new { a = ug2.GroupId, b = groupId } equals new { a = gr.GroupId, b = gr.GroupId }
   select new { ug1, ug2 })
  .FirstOrDefault()) != null;
 }
}
```